# magento 1.9 catalog search index cannot initialize the indexer process on localhost

Tags: magento-1.9, indexer, reindex

Can Magento 1.9 catalog search index invoke the indexer process on local host?

Answer (score 0):

saving a product will invoke an update, if `catalog search index` is set to `update on save`

Comment: kindly guide in details please